# type mismatch after updating Scala from 2.12.14 to 2.13.8

Tags: scala, playframework

As a Java Engineer, I am new to Scala and am having difficulty resolving this issue.

I am creating a new app and migrating one of the services from a different app that uses Scala 2.12.14, though the new app uses 2.13.8. There seem to be some deprecated collections. I would appreciate it if you could help me solve this problem easily.

[image: import]

[image: type mismatch error]

Comment: Just hover your mouse over that crossed out line, it'll tell you what to do. Also, don't use mutable collections.

Answer (score 5):

These converters have been moved; the API documentation [states](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.8/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html)

> Deprecated (Since version 2.13.0) Use scala.jdk.CollectionConverters instead